# Export PrimeFaces PanelGrid

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, panelgrid

I'm trying to export a `PanelGrid`(xls/pdf), not possible via `DataExporter` (specific for `DataTable` type parameter), is it possible using a `CustomExporter` ? 
 Do I have to use a non primefaces mean (eg JQuery) or do I have to change my code to ensure that this `PanelGrid` becomes a `DataTable` in order to be able to export it ? 
 Can't find this kind of information on the net.

Thank you for your help,

Julien

Comment: The source of the PrimeFaces exporter is open. You can download it, see how it is done for the dataTable and do the same for the datagrid.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that.